# POST API Issue - Not functioning

Tags: php, api

Good afternoon,

I'm having trouble with an api POST request - it simply isn't going anywhere, it's not showing on the API log at all - I've got various get requests which work fine but this one just doesn't - I'm unsure what I am doing wrong.

```
public function broadband_plan(){
        $common = array();
        $common['main_menu'] = 'Broadband plan';

        $cli_or_postcode = isset($_GET["cli_or_postcode"]) ? $_GET["cli_or_postcode"] : "";
        $district_id = isset($_GET["district_id"]) ? $_GET["district_id"] : "";
        $sub_premises = isset($_GET["sub_premises"]) ? $_GET["sub_premises"] : "";
        $premises_name = isset($_GET["premises_name"]) ? $_GET["premises_name"] : "";
        $thoroughfare_number = isset($_GET["thoroughfare_number"]) ? $_GET["thoroughfare_number"] : "";
        $thoroughfare_name = isset($_GET["thoroughfare_name"]) ? $_GET["thoroughfare_name"] : "";
        $locality = isset($_GET["locality"]) ? $_GET["locality"] : "";
        $postcode = isset($_GET["postcode"]) ? $_GET["postcode"] : "";
        $nad_key = isset($_GET["nad_key"]) ? $_GET["nad_key"] : "";
        $post_town = isset($_GET["post_town"]) ? $_GET["post_town"] : "";
        $county = isset($_GET["county"]) ? $_GET["county"] : "";
        $district_id = isset($_GET["district_id"]) ? $_GET["district_id"] : "";

        $request = array();
        $request['apiUsername'] = 'XXXXXXX';
        $request['apiPassword'] = 'XXXXXXX';
        $request['encryption']   = 'SHA-512';
        $request['platform']     = 'LIVE';
        $request['method']       = 'POST';
        
        $address = '{
            "sub_premises": $sub_premises,
            "premises_name": $premises_name,
            "thoroughfare_number": $thoroughfare_number,
            "thoroughfare_name": $thoroughfare_name,
            "post_town": $post_town,
            "postcode": $postcode,
            "district_id": $district_id,
            "nad_key": $nad_key
        }';
        $address = json_encode($address);

        $request['url'] = "/broadband/availability" . $address;
        
        
    
        $broadband_plan_detail = array();
        if (!empty($address)) {
            $broadband_plan_detail = $this->get_plan($request);
        }

        return view('front.broadband_plan',compact('common','broadband_plan_detail'));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The $address after $address = json_encode($address); will be an object, it cannot be concatenated as a string in $request['url'] = "/broadband/availability" . $address;

Please check your API URL and ensure you follow their structure, for example if the API URL accept the parameters as GET request, you can pass the parameters likes:

$request['url'] = "/broadband/availability?sub_premises=" . $sub_premises . "&premises_name=" . $premises_name...

Base on your code, the API method is POST, so you might need to prepare the parameters as an array.

Comment: Thank you, Mark, to clarify - how would I resolve that ?

Comment: I have update the answer.